# Playing audio files with sine wave from arduino

Tags: pins, sd-card

So, when searching for a way to play audio files through the Arduino, I came across this site: [How to play WAV audio files with Arduino Uno and MicroSD card](http://maxoffsky.com/maxoffsky-blog/how-to-play-wav-audio-files-with-arduino-uno-and-microsd-card/)

This seems like a really good library (although I haven't had the time to really play around with it yet). Has anyone used this before, and, if so, is it a good library to use, or do you know of better ones out there which you would recommend?

Comment: The library works fine, and you'll find details from the developer of the PCM audio library [here](http://tmrh20.blogspot.in/2014/02/arduino-wav-playback-direct-from-sd.html).

Comment: http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/PCMAudio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used some time ago the TMRPCM library that the tutorial you linked used and I was very satisfied.

It doesn't take too much space and it has some really unique and neat features like the possibility to use two speakers instead of one to reproduce stereo audio (Unfortunately you need a more powerful AVR IC, surely not an UNO board/328 IC for this feature if you don't want to occur in bad reproduction)

From [GitHub's wiki](https://github.com/TMRh20/TMRpcm/wiki):

> All 328 based boards: Arduino Uno, Nano, Duemilanove, etc
>
> Mega Types: 1280, 2560, etc
>
> No Due support currently.

You can only have WAV files on the SD but they can be very large (other libraries limit you to a specific maximum size/duration) and you need to connect the SD to the arduino via SPI (as far as I know it is the only way to communicate directly with an SD card).

Also, you will need to convert the files to 8 bit WAV (so it's faster and easier for the arduino to reproduce the sound) with sample rate from 8 to 32khz, mono audio.

Be careful just because you'll need to power the SD with 3.3 volts otherwise you'll fry the entire card.

> Most of the extra features require more memory, more program space, and in some cases, more processing power for playback Some of them are still being fine tuned. Please keep this in mind when enabling these features.

If you want to take a look, [go to this page](https://github.com/TMRh20/TMRpcm/wiki/Advanced-Features) for more informations on the advanced features

A last thing that I have to say is that the functions are really straightforward:

```
TMRpcm audio;
audio.play("filename");    plays a file
audio.play("filename",30); plays a file starting at 30 seconds into the track
audio.speakerPin = 11;     set to 5,6,11 or 46 for Mega, 9 for Uno, Nano, etc.
audio.disable();           disables the timer on output pin and stops the music
audio.stopPlayback();      stops the music, but leaves the timer running
audio.isPlaying();         returns 1 if music playing, 0 if not
audio.pause();             pauses/unpauses playback
audio.quality(1);          Set 1 for 2x oversampling
audio.volume(0);           1(up) or 0(down) to control volume
audio.setVolume(0);        0 to 7. Set volume level
audio.loop(1);             0 or 1. Can be changed during playback for full control of looping.
```